# Google Sheets used to show current users but now it doesn't

Tags: google-sheets

Google Sheets used to show current users on a spreadsheet.  Now it doesn't. I can't find a setting to fix this.  How can I see who is active on a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

I am still able to see the others current on the sheet?

[image]

The speech bubble and users are not present if no one else has the sheet open.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the "compact menu" setting on you can't see most of the stuff from the bar up top.